# How do I setup a default committer different from my default author on git?

Tags: git, github, environments

I'd like to have a default Committer that's different from my default Author, as I want to differentiate commits made from my local env and those from testing env. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, [git considers as Author and Committer what's on your `user.email` and `user.name` config values](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-useremail) - and there's no way to set that from config files.

However, both values [can be overridden on a per-commit-basis using environment variables](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree#_commit_information). Thus, if you set these in your shell settings you should be able to set a different committer, permanently.

Example (at your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`):

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Deploy server"
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="deploy@server.dev"
```

---

> Quick note: to set up author user/email use as follows (or write those entries directly in `~/.gitconfig` if
>   you know the file format):
>
> ```
> $ git config --global user.name "Igor Santos"
> $ git config --global user.email "igor.santos@example.com"
> ```